# Local static variable linkage

Tags: c++, clang, static-methods, linkage

Can somebody explain why compilation of these two snippets behaves differently (at least on OSX):

```
struct A {
    static int func()
    {
            static int value __attribute__((weak));
            return value++;
    }
};
```

passes but

```
//struct A
//{
    /*static*/ int func()
    {
            static int value __attribute__((weak));
            return value++;
    }
//}
```

fails with an error:

```
    1.cpp:6:35: error: weak declaration cannot have internal linkage
                static int value __attribute__((weak));
```

Compilation command line:

```
     clang++ 1.cpp -shared
```

Comment: Generally, in C++, names declared at block scope have no linkage. For vendor extensions, you need to consult your vendor's documentation.

Comment: What if I have this code statically linked to shared library and binary which also links same shared library? What will happen with  static int value in that case?

Comment: There are several rules as to when a symbol is internally  externally linkable. In the first case value is essentially a global variable hidden inside a static member function which will default to external linkage. However when put into a regular function will deafault to internal linkage. Try adding extern to value declaration and see if it solves linkage error